# Read CSV cells; write to dictionary/array

Tags: python, arrays, csv, dictionary

I am attempting to create a python script that will read CSV files and for instance, count each time the letter 'a' appears or the integer 1 shows up.

Currently I have adapted code to set a list to a row of data read from the csv file and I'm trying to make a loop that will track that data via an array or dictionary.

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-

import os

os.chdir('F:\Muiltimedia Tools\Projects\KippurCat Arts™\Python\Input')

'Initialize variables'
checklet = 'x';count = 0;index = 0


"Import Excel Data"
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=':', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in reader:
        print row
        alist = row




print alist.count(1)

print count
```

Additionly I am looking for an easy way to convert time data in the format of 00:00:00 to seconds.

Keep in mind that I'm really new to python, but I have prior coding experience from some other basic languages.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

def strToSeconds(st):
    h,m,s = st.split(':')
    return 3600*int(h) + 60*int(m) + int(s)

def main():
    fname = "F:/Multimedia Tools/Projects/KippurCat Arts™/Python/Input/test.csv"

    # read data
    c = Counter()
    with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
        reader =  csv.reader(fname, delimiter=':', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        for row in reader:
            c.update(row)

    # show results of interest
    for val in ('a', 1):
        print("Number of {}s: {}".format(val, c[val]))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, ive been reading a lot around the forums, and came to a similiar solution, but it is still valuable to see another solution that suppliments mine.